# Centralized storage for large text files

Tags: sql, file, optimization, nosql

What should do system : store/manage centralized large(100 - 400 mb) text files

What to store : lines from text file, for some files lines must be unique, metadata about file(filename, comment, last update etc.) also must be stored position in file( on same file may be different positions for different applications)

Operations : concurrent get lines from file (100 - 400 lines on query), add lines(also 100 - 400 lines), exporting is not critical - can be scheduled

So which storage to use SQL DBMS - too slow, i think, maybe a noSQL solution ?

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL: Cassandra is an option (you can store it line by line or groups of lines I guess), Voldemort is not too bad, you might even get away with using MongoDB but not sure it fits the "large files" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

400 MiB will be completely served from the caches on every non-ridiculous database server. Insofar, the choice of database does not really matter too much, any database will be able to deliver fast (though there are different kinds of "fast", it depends what you need).

If you are really desperate for raw speed, you can go with something like `redis`. Again, 400 MiB is no challenge for that.

SQL might be slightly slower (but not *that* much) but has the huge advantage of being flexible. Flexibility, generality, and the presence of a "built-in programming language" are not free, but they should not have a too bad impact, because either way returning data from the buffer cache works more or less at the speed of RAM.

If you ever figure that you need a different database at a later time, SQL will let you do it with a few commands, or if you ever want something else you've not planned for, SQL will do. There is no guarantee that doing something different will be feasible with a simple key-value store.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about performance for such rather "small" datasets. Really, every kind of DB will serve that well, worry not. Come again when your datasets are several dozens of gigabytes in size.

If you are 100% sure that you will *definitively never* need the extras that a fully blown SQL database system offers, go with NoSQL to shave off a few microseconds. Otherwise, just stick with it to be on the safe side.

**EDIT:**
To elaborate, consider that a "somewhat lower class" desktop has upwards of 2 GiB (usually rather 4 GiB) nowadays, and a typical "no big deal" server has something like 32 GiB. In that light, 400 MiB is nothing. Typical network uplink on a server (unless you are willing to pay extra) are 100 mibit/s.

A 400 MiB text file might have somewhere around a million lines. That boils down to 6-7 memory accesses for a "typical SQL server", and to 2 memory accesses plus the time needed to calculate a hash for a "typical NoSQL server". Which is, give or take few a dozen cycles, the same in either case -- something around a half a **micro**second on a relatively slow system.

Add to that a few dozen microseconds the first time a query is executed, because it must be parsed, validated, and optimized, if you use SQL.

Network latency is somewhere around 2 to 3 **milli**seconds if you're lucky. That's 3 to 4 orders of magnitude more for establishing a connection, sending a request to the server, and receiving an answer. Compared to that, it seems ridiculous to worry whether the query takes 517 or 519 microseconds. If there are 1-2 routers in between, it becomes even more pronounced.
The same is true for bandwidth. You can in theory push around 119 MiB/s over a 1 Gibit/s link assuming maximum sized frames and assuming no ACKs and assuming absolutely no other traffic, and zero packet loss. RAM delivers in the tens of GiB per second without trouble.